# Prove that $ a^2-4b \neq2$ if $ a,b \in \mathbb{ Z}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My solution :
We suppose that is true. Then by contradiction:

$a^2-4b-2=0$

$a^2=4b+2$

$a=2(b+1/2) ^{0.5}$

then $(b+1/2)$ is fraction and rooted by $0.5$ so the square root of any fraction $+$ any-Integer will give fraction so then $a$ must be fraction, not an integer. Contradiction.

Then $a^2 -4b \neq 2$?

Is that a good proof?

Comment: The easiest solution is to note that $a$ must be even. But then the LHS is a multiple of $4$ but the RHS is not.

Comment: but is my solution right ?

Comment: So , you are proving that $a^2-4b$ is _not_ equal to $2$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose this is true then $a^2=2+4b$

$\implies 2|a^2$

$\implies 2|a$

$\implies $ 4 is a multiple of L.H.S. but it is not a multiple of R.H.S.

which leads to a contradiction

Comment: just please adjust the notation I can not understand what is |  means

Comment: $2|a$  means "2 divides a"

Comment: but how is 4 multiple of L.H.S and vise versa ?

Comment: See your equation is $ a^2-4b =2$ and $2|a$ So $2^2|a^2~i.e.~4|a^2$.

Comment: OK, what about R.H.S what is the wrong that makes the paradox ? could you please explain

Comment: again see your equation $a^2-4b=2$

$\implies 4((\frac{a}{2})^2-b)=2$

$\implies (\frac{a}{2})^2-b=\frac{1}{2}$

Now you can easily see this is a contradiction

Comment: so why then a,b can not be an integer, still not clear for me, excuse me I am not mathematician :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24899/discussion-between-tandee-holwa-and-absolute-friend).

Answer (score 5):

Your proof is incorrect because you make the assertion that "$\sqrt{b+\frac{1}{2}}$ is a fraction so $2 \sqrt{b+\frac{1}{2}}$ is also a fraction." It may very well turn out to be a whole number! You will need some other kind of reasoning to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

no, I think your argument about the square root is not clear or proven. Also

How about

a^2=4b+2
Suppose a and b are integers, then 4b+2 is even, so a^2 is also an integer and a must be even. Let 2c=a, then we get 4c^2 = 4b + 2, c^2 - b = 1/2, we cannot have the difference of two integers being fractional, so we have a contradiction, hence a and b both cannot be integers.
(sorry my earlier proof mistakenly tried to show either a or b were integers).

Comment: good job man, I like it

Answer (score 2):

Suppose
$a^2=4b+2
$.
$a$ must be of the form
$2c$ or $2c+1$
(i.e., even or odd).

If $a=2c$,
then
$2 = (2c)^2-4b
= 4c^2-4b
= 4(c^2-b)
$.
But 4 divides the right side but not the left,
so this is impossible.

If $a=2c+1$,
then
$2 = (2c+1)^2-4b
= 4c^2+4c+1-4b
= 4(c^2+c-b)+1
$.
But the left side is even
and the right side is odd,
so this is also impossible.

Note that this works,
with minor changes,
for
$a^2 = 4b+3
$.

Comment: Since $b\in\mathbb Z$, $a$ cannot be of the form $2c+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a^2-4b=2$. Reduce both sides modulo 4 to obtain $a^2=2\mod{4}$. But $a\equiv \{-1,0,1,2\}$, so $a^2\equiv \{0,1\}$. Hence there is no solution.